# How can i return with Content type in laravel?

Tags: java, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use a Laravel application as an Android Studio project.

I am trying to send a httpsrequest from Java, how do I return a response?

Like we use in PHP to return response as JSON as `header('Content-Type: application/json');` at the header oh .php file and the message as:

`$response["message"] = "Signin succsessfully done."; 
echo json_encode($response);`

so in laravel i am trying to return response as:

`return response()->json(['success'=>1])
     ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');`

but it's not working

in my Java file `JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);`

So How do i do this?

edit: this is how i am calling from .java

```
  JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);`
 } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Rjn_login_error"+e.getMessage());
        }






/**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /*
                  Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 */
                if (success == 1) {
                    // jsonarray found
}}}
```

So when i am using calling the url as `http://website.com/test.php` and in the `test.php` `

```
    $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Signin succsessfully done.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
```

and its working perfactly

But when i tried to `return response json` from laravel controller it's not working ..

Comment: Can you provide API request code, also did you try locally or on a server?

Comment: i tried on server

Answer (score 3):

Pass headers as third param to response helper

```php
return response([
    'status' => 'success'
], 200, ['Content-Type => application/json']);
```

Results in

[image]

You can also instruct the response to be JSON like so

```php
return response()->json([
    'status' => 'success'
], 200);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: it's the same as using `response()->json(['status' => 'success']);`

Comment: yes it's same as response()->json(['status' => 'success']); but not working in my java code

Answer (score 0):

When you use `return response()->json(['success'=>1]);` you dont need to set the content type to `'application/json'`. The method `json()` will do it automatically.

If you're still not getting the right response header, it might be due to one of your custom/modified middleware that is setting the `'Content-Type'` header.